# How can I parse a date from a meta file and store it into the mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to parse a meta file with php and store the data into my database. In this case I want to find the line that starts with `#`and safe the date into mySQL database:

```
18923081293801293.animal=cat
#Tue Jun 14 12:40:44 CEST 2015
18923081293801293.name=Fred
18923081293801293.age=24
```

This is my code so far. It is parsing `animal`, `name` and `age`.

```
                        $properties = array();

                        foreach ($linesArray AS $line) {
                            if (false !== ($pos = strpos($line, '='))) {
                                $prop=array();    
                                $prop[trim(substr($line, 0, $pos))] = trim(substr($line, $pos + 1));
                                $lineContArray = explode("=", $line);
                                $identArray = explode(".", $lineContArray[0]);

                                $ident = $identArray[0];
                                $type = $identArray[1];     

                                $value = $lineContArray[1];

                                $found = 0;
                                for ($i=0; $i<count($properties); $i++) {
                                    if ($properties[$i]['number'] == $ident) {
                                        $properties[$i][$type]= $value;
                                        $found=1;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                if ($found == 0) { 
                                    if (!empty($type)) { 
                                        $properties[] = array('number' => $ident, $type => $value); 
                                    } else { 
                                    $properties[] = array($ident => $value); } 
                                            }
                                    }
                                }


$sql = "INSERT INTO farm (animal,name,age) values(?,?,?) ";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
foreach($properties as $row) {
   $q->execute(array($row['animal'], $row['name'], $row['age']));
}
```

But I do not know how to parse the date line and get it into my database as a date (column type: datetime).

Comment: INSERT INTO `tablename` (`columnname`) VALUES ( '2015-08-04');

Comment: from where do you get this date string?

Comment: That depends on what type the column you want to store the date in has. There are [more than one alternative](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html).

Comment: The date is inside my text-file

Comment: Please edit your question to include that information.

Comment: the biggest problem for me is the parsing

Comment: @Anders I updated my querstion

Comment: are you sure that the date will be in second line?

Comment: @SubinThomas I didn't want to parse via line, because the line could change, so I thought about pasing it with the `#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the date from the file you need to check for a `#` at the beginning of a line inside the loop:

```
foreach ($linesArray AS $line) {
    // Check for # as first character (but only if there is a first character).
    if (strlen($line) && $line[0] == '#') {
        // Convert everything except the first character to a date.
        $date = strtotime(substr($line, 1));
        // Convert it back to a string in a format that MySQL likes.
        $strDate = date("y-m-d H:i:s", $date);
    }
    // Here the rest of your old continues.
    if (false !== ($pos = strpos($line, '='))) {
        ...
```

Then you can just insert it in the database like you insert the other values. Not sure this fits exactly with your code as I don't understand all of it, but it should give you a hint of how to do it at least.

Comment: Thank you, there must be a mistake in the line: `$date = strtodate($line);`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to remove the `#`. Will fix. I tried running the example value through the function, and I got a date in return. Didn't check to carefully it was right, though.

Answer (score 1):

This following code to convert the line to date, which can be inserted to DB.

```
if ($line[0] == '#')    //if line start with
{
$line = str_replace('#', '',$line); //remove # from line
$dates = new DateTime($line);       //convert line to date time
$reformdate = $dates -> format("Y-m-d H:i:s");   //format date to as required style
}
```

create a column with datatype "datetime" and you can insert like following example.

```
INSERT INTO tablename (dateandtime) VALUES ('$reformdate');
```

in your case add $reformdate to $properties array and add it in PDO.